# Java practice question with objects and inheritance, need advice (beginner)

Tags: java

First thing, can someone check my code if it's going on the right side. I don't understand one thing, `add the toString()` method that prints the information about a ship, toString method only accepts String as a return, but all my variables are ints. So how am I supposed to return the information there?

When I am trying to add an ArrayList in the Fleet class, I am getting `ArrayList cannot be resolved a type`.

And the last part where it says in `main()`, is this supposed to be in the Ship class or the Fleet class?

The question I'm working on.

Define the class Ship containing side lengths, number of passengers, displacement, unique number ship, three versions of the overloaded constructor, a method to calculate the surface area (it should
assumed to be rectangular in shape).

Then define the classes:

- Destroyer inheriting from the Ship class and supplemented with information about the force of fire and the number of
  guns,
- Aircraft carrier inherits from Destroyer class and adds data about the number of aircraft it can carry.
- To both classes (Destroyer and Aircraft Carrier) add the toString() method that prints the relevant
  information about the ships.

Finally, define a Fleet class containing:

- A list (ArrayList) with elements of type Ship, which will be filled dynamically by
  the addToFleet(Ship) method created for this purpose
- The fleetStrength() method which counts the firepower, number of passengers and guns in the fleet
- In main() create a Fleet type object and fill it with random data. Print information about
  ships (use toString() and fleetStrength()).

```java
public class Ship {
    protected int id;
    protected int sideA;
    protected int sideB;
    protected int passengers;
    protected int displacement;

    public Ship() {};
    
    public Ship(int id, it sideA, int sideB, int passengers, int displacement) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sideA = sideA;
        this.sideB = sideB;
        this.passengers = passengers;
        this.displacement = displacement;
    }
    public int calculateSurfaceArea(){
        return this.sideA*this.sideB;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Destroyer extends Ship {
    protected int force;
    protected int guns;
 
    Public Destroyer() {}
    
    Public Destroyer(int a, int b) {
        this.force = a;
        this.guns = b;
    }
}
```

```java
public class AircraftCarrier extends Destroyer {
    protected int carriers;
    
    Public AirCraftCarrier() {}; 
}
```

```java
public class Fleet extends Ship {   
    protected var shipList = new ArrayList<Ship>();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toString` is a method that Java uses when you use `System.out.println` on the object (or in general when anything calls `toString`). In this case, your teacher wants you to create a custom `toString` method which will print out custom information about your class. For example, if I had a class `Dog` with an `int` `age`, I could override it to do something like:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "Age: " + age;
}
```

So that if I use `System.out.println` on the object, it will print the `age` value. For example, `System.out.println(new Dog(5));` -> `Age: 5` (where 5 is the age). You can try applying the same to your own code by using the method header provided above as a starter, and using the `ints` you have to create a readable String.

As for `ArrayList`, you may have forgot to import the class, causing the cannot be resolved to a type error.

Your access modifiers (`public`, `protected`, etc), seem to be incorrect. Modifiers are always lowercase, so turn `Public` -> `public`.

Comment: In your example, toString() would return `"Age: 5"` not just `"5"`.

Comment: Hey - I believe this does answer the question adequately so it's appropriate that you did leave this as an answer rather than a comment. (Comments are generally just short messages to ask for clarification or context anyhow.)

Comment: @David Conrad oops. I corrected it. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: No worries I already upvoted you. :) I agree with Sam that this works as an answer.